# Twitter Social Sign On Not Returning Email Of the Twitter Users

Tags: community, twitter, social-sign-on

**Scenario A:**
We are trying to set up Social Sign-on using twitter, authentication is successful but email not returned by Twitter on login.

We are not using the custom app from Twitter. RegistrationHandler is the default generated by Salesforce. On Debugging we found that the Email Is null that's why Query failed. Is there any setting from twitter? are we missing something?

**Scenario B:**
We even tried to store the twitter handle in a custom field, queried the user based on that, but this is not working too, there is no error in this case but it's returning back to the login page of the community.

Comment: Did you request it on Twitter side: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/manage-account-settings/api-reference/get-account-verify_credentials

Comment: @identigral I have already gone through this, I didn't find any of the API returning email address in response, could you please point out any specific?

Comment: This part: _The "Request email addresses from users" checkbox is available under the app permissions on developer.twitter.com. Privacy Policy URL and Terms of Service URL fields must be completed in the app settings in order for email address access to function. If enabled, users will be informed via the oauth/authorize dialog that your app can access their email address_

Comment: @identigral
But we are not using the app from Twitter, we are letting Salesforce create it automatically. Do we need to implement our own twitter app?

Comment: The "app" on the Twitter side is mostly config but, yes, you need to do that to get the email. Whether you can use the generated SF code as is or you need to tweak it is a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Use Test-Only Initialization URL of Auth. Provider to understand the different data attributes you are going to get.

If you are continuing to use the Salesforce Managed authentication app then find the registration handler code for Twitter here - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sso_provider_twitter.htm&type=5